# Firemonkey HD Form will not Minimize when using the Taskbar

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I have a Firemonkey HD application targeted for the 32-bit Windows platform. Clicking the applications Minimize button from within the Form works as expected and will restore when its taskbar button is clicked, however it will **not** Minimize this way. I can only Minimize from within the Form. The Windows live preview thumbnail will also not display the Form when it is hovered over with the mouse.

This happens with just a blank new Firemonkey HD application and I get the same behaviour in Windows XP Professional, Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 8

I thought at first it could be due to the MainFormOnTaskbar property however this I found out does not apply to Firemonkey and cannot be used.

Is this some limitation of Firemonkey? Why does this happen?

Comment: I've seen this issue all over the place, even with software produced by Microsoft themselves, such as Word and Outlook.

Comment: @JerryDodge - I have never seen this behaviour before but thanks for letting me know it is not just me then.

Comment: I would just like to add that I have MS Office 2010 and Word does not behave this way on my system.

Comment: Doesn't mean that's the issue though, could be anything. And the problems I face are spontaneous, not all the time.

Comment: @JerryDodge - ok thanks this happens always and is not intermittent.

Comment: @KenWhite - oh... thank you for trying, now I am worried! so it is just my system then. I DO have a multi monitor system (x4 screens) that has Display Fusion installed which adds a little icon to the left of the Minimize button. I will now test without this active then and see if this comes into play.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to reproduce it (that's why I deleted my comment). Not sure why it happens, though.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I think @JerryDodge is wrong. While I've (on rare occasions) had this happen with other applications, the vast majority of the time applications work properly in the task bar. This indeed seems to be a Firemonkey issue. (That isn't surprising, as it's not strictly a WIndows framework; other platforms may not have this issue because they don't have the same functionality as Windows. There are some compatibility issues when trying to be cross-platform without using the native functionality of each OS to do so; it's one of the major drawbacks to trying to be cross-platform.)

Comment: @KenWhite I wasn't indicating a right or wrong answer, just the fact that I've experienced similar issues and suggesting OP might be having the same issues. When it happens to me, it happens for certain applications for periods of time.

Comment: @KenWhite - thanks for your response. When I first discovered this yesterday I thought it may have been a well know issue but I searched high and low for it but it seems not so. I now wonder how many others have had this issue but never raised it or is Firemonkey HD not that widely used? Yesterday was the very first time I actually looked into Firemonkey HD but only because I wanted to use some of the effects in a Win32/64 application.